# Problems with a merge inside a loop

Tags: r, loops, merge

I have a specific data.frame (data) that I would like to merge with more than 40 other data.frames (df.1 df.40) always using the same column "IID".
I first create a vector with the df.n. The first 5:

```
names<-c(df.1,df.2,df.3,df.4,df.5)
```

Then I tried to use this script without success:

```
lst<-list()
for (i in names){
lst[[i]]<-merge(data,[i],by="IID")
}
```

Then my intention was to to this:

```
new_names<-c(d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5)

for (i in 1:length(lst)) {
  assign(new_names[i], lst[[i]])
}
```

However I could not get right the first loop. something is wrong with how I can the loop at the merge function.

Comment: The line `names<-c(df.1,df.2,df.3,df.4,df.5)` doesn't make much sense to me. Is that supposed to be `names<-c("df.1","df.2","df.3","df.4","df.5")`? Or do you have a list of data.frames?

Comment: No I don't have a list of data.frames. I also tried with the " ". But didn't work. Perhaps that was right...

Comment: do all data frames have same number of columns with same column names ?

Comment: Yes, same columns and same columns names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `get` so it actually gets the dataframe you want to merge. Like this:

```
lst<-list()
for (i in names){
  lst[[i]]<-merge(data,get(i),by="IID")
}
```